# CakePHP 1.3: Alaxos ACL not working due to a plugin named Configurations

Tags: cakephp, configuration, acl

I have been using Alaxos CakePHP ACLplugin for my site, which is great. However, I installed a Configuration plugin and if I run ACL, I get the following error:

```
Undefined property: AclController::$Configuration [APP/app_controller.php, line 52]
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /home/bravanews/public_html/app/app_controller.php on line 52
```

In order for me to run ACL and update my permissions table I have to comment out the following code in my `app_controller.php` file:

```
$this->Configuration->load('CFG');
```

Does anyone know why ACL does not recognized this plugin? Isnt ACL supposed to inherit app_controller functions?

**EDIT: << PROBLEM FIXED >> I used `var $uses = array('Configuration.Configuration');` in the ACL controller and it fixed my problem. This ACL controller had a line that says `var $uses = null;`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See EDIT section of the question for the answer.